# How to switch between one click mouse and mouse hold down?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When it's one click i want the character to Walk to the mouse position.
But if it's holding down the mouse button i want it to rotate the character.
But for some reason it's all the time on the Idle state. So when i make one click the character jump in small jump and not walking to the mouse position.

If i will remove the whole part of the if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) then when clicking the mouse it will walk fine to the mouse position but once added this part he will not walk.

```
void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            _animator.CrossFade("Walk", 0);
            Plane playerPlane = new Plane(Vector3.up, transform.position);
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            float hitdist = 0.0f;

            if (playerPlane.Raycast(ray, out hitdist))
            {
                Vector3 targetPoint = ray.GetPoint(hitdist);
                targetPosition = ray.GetPoint(hitdist);
                targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetPoint - transform.position);
                destination = targetPosition;
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            _animator.CrossFade("Idle", 0);
            RaycastHit hit;
            Ray ray1 = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray1, out hit) && hit.collider.name != "ThirdPersonController")
            {
                transform.LookAt(hit.point);
            }
            else
            {
                transform.LookAt(ray1.GetPoint(100));  //the number here is compltely arbitrary
            }
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Input.GetMouseButton(int)` returns true *always* if the mouse button is being pressed. `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(int)` returns true *only* on the first frame during which the mouse button is clicked.

So given your code, the possibilities are:

- No button is being pressed. None of the `if` blocks are entered.
- This is the *exact* frame when the mouse button was clicked. Both of the `if` blocks are executed. Your animator state is set to `Walk` and then immediately to `Idle` and your character doesn't move.
- The mouse button was pressed down a few frames ago and is still being held down. Only the second `if` block is executed. Your animator state is set to `Idle` and the character doesn't move.

If you have decided to use this particular control scheme, you should consider implementing some sort of delay - maybe mouse button presses shorter than 0.2s should count as a *click* and presses longer than 0.2s should count as a *hold*. This way your predicates won't overlap.